# An arkanoid game made with python turtle

Tags: python, game, turtle-graphics

My idea is to understand the limits of python turtle, it is a conscious choice and I understand that **any** other library would probably suit better. I don't use OOP, as I don't think that it would make any difference in such a small game. Right now I would say that the game is playable, but nowhere enjoyable. I am looking for any suggestions to make the code cleaner and simpler, as well as for general techniques to make the game smother. I have a few minor questions:

1. What would be the best way to keep the speed of the ball constant? Right now I am trying to maintain a constant frame rate, but it does not work properly.
2. Right now you can see, that the ball is jumping forward after each frame rather then moving continuously. Is there any trick to make it smoother visually?
3. There is some issue with the ball bouncing against the wall later than it should, is there any way to fix it?

```
from turtle import *
from math import ceil
from time import time

setup(500, 500, 0, 0)

moving_right = False
moving_left  = False

board_x = 250
board_y = 400
board_width = 50

ball_x = 250
ball_y = 200
ball_radius = 10

v_x = 5
v_y = 5

block_size = 25

blocks=[
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
        [0,0,1,2,2,2,2,1,0,0],
        [0,0,1,2,3,3,2,1,0,0],
        [0,0,1,2,3,3,2,1,0,0],
        [0,0,1,2,2,2,2,1,0,0],
        [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    ]

# The following functions are just wrappers,
# the only useful thing they are doing is
# moving the (0, 0) point from the centre of the screen
# to the top-left corner
def rect(x, y, width, height, fill, outline=None):
    if outline is None:
        outline = fill
        
    penup()
    goto(x-window_width()/2, -y+window_height()/2)
    pendown()
    color(outline, fill)

    begin_fill()
    for i in range(2):
        forward(width)
        right(90)
        forward(height)
        right(90)
    end_fill()
    penup()

def circ(x, y, radius, fill, outline=None):
    if outline is None:
        outline = fill
        
    penup()
    goto(x-window_width()/2, radius-y+window_height()/2)
    pendown()
    color(outline, fill)

    begin_fill()
    circle(-radius, steps=10)
    end_fill()

# This algorithm is copypasted from
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/21096179/6172914

# Returns True if the ball collided with a rect
# with an (x, y) top left corner and w and h for
# width and height
def collided(x, y, w, h):
    dx = abs(ball_x - x - w/2);
    dy = abs(ball_y - y - h/2);

    if dx > (w/2 + ball_radius):
        return False
    
    if dy > (h/2 + ball_radius):
        return False

    if dx <= w/2:
        return True 
    if dy <= h/2:
        return True
    
    return (dx-w/2)**2+(dy-h/2)**2<=(ball_radius**2)

# If the ball collides with something,
# this method would change v_x and v_y as needed
# the last if is sort of random, but works
def collide_with_rect(x, y, w, h):
    global v_x, v_y
    if not collided(x, y, w, h):
        return

    changed = False

    if x <= ball_x < x + w:
        v_y *= -1
        changed = True

    if y <= ball_y < y + h:
        v_x *= -1
        changed = True

    if not changed:
        if ball_x < x:
            v_x = -abs(v_x)

        else:
            v_x = abs(v_x)

        if ball_y < y:
            v_y = -abs(v_y)

        else:
            v_y = abs(v_y)

# This function sort of works,
# but sometimes you can see that it does not
def collide_with_walls():
    global ball_x, ball_y, v_x, v_y
    if ball_x >= window_width()-ball_radius or ball_x < ball_radius:
        v_x *= -1

    if ball_y >= window_height()-ball_radius or ball_y < ball_radius:
        v_y *= -1

def collide_with_blocks():
    for x in range(10):
        for y in range(10):
            if blocks[x][y]!=0:
                xr = x*block_size
                yr = y*block_size

                if collided(xr, yr, block_size, block_size):
                    collide_with_rect(xr, yr, block_size, block_size)
                    blocks[x][y] = 0
                    
def move_ball():
    global ball_x, ball_y, v_x, v_y

    collide_with_walls()
    collide_with_blocks()

    collide_with_rect(board_x, board_y, board_width, 10)
            
    ball_x += v_x
    ball_y += v_y

def draw_blocks():
    blocks_colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', ]

    for x in range(10):
        for y in range(10):
            if blocks[x][y]!=0:
                color = blocks_colors[blocks[x][y]-1]
                rect(x*block_size, y*block_size, block_size, block_size, color)

def tick():
    global ball_x, ball_y, board_x, last

    # I need this variable to keep a constant framerate
    # but it still seems to float one way or another
    start = time()
    clear()

    if moving_right:
        board_x += 10

    if moving_left:
        board_x -= 10 
    
    move_ball()
    
    rect(board_x, board_y, board_width, 10, 'brown')
    circ(ball_x, ball_y, ball_radius, 'green')
    draw_blocks()

    spend = (time()-start)*1000
    ontimer(tick, ceil(50-spend))

def start_left():
    global moving_left
    moving_left = True

def start_right():
    global moving_right
    moving_right = True

def stop_left():
    global moving_left
    moving_left = False

def stop_right():
    global moving_right
    moving_right = False

tracer(False)
onkeypress(start_left, 'a')
onkeypress(start_right, 'd')

onkeyrelease(stop_left, 'a')
onkeyrelease(stop_right, 'd')

ontimer(tick,20)

listen()
mainloop()
```